# mongodb query based on date + x days from the documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

consider this mongo collection with following documents and props.

```
{sku: '3344', frequency: 30, lastProccessedDate: 2021-01-07 15:18:07.576Z},
{sku: '2233', frequency: 30, lastProccessedDate: 2021-02-16 15:18:07.576Z},
{sku: '1122', frequency: 30, lastProccessedDate: 2021-04-13 15:18:07.576Z}
```

I want to query and get all the documents with `(lastProcessedDate + frequency (days)) <= current date`.

Essentially in SQL world this is possible to do it, but I can't figure it out to do it in mongo or even if it is possible to do it.

In SQL this would be something like
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(lastProcessedDate), INTERVAL frequency DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') <= CURDATE()`

If it is not possible I know I can store the calculated date in the document and just query based on that but you know I want to know if it is possible to do it.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can't give you a solution for mongoose. But here is the Mongo query that returns the result you want:

```
db.getCollection("yourCollection").aggregate([
{
   $project: {
       _id: 1,
       sku: 1,
       frequency: 1,
       lastProccessedDate: 1,
       shiftedDate: {
           $add: [
               "$lastProccessedDate", { $multiply: [ 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "$frequency" ] }
           ]
       }
   } 
}, {
    $match: {
        shiftedDate: { $lte: new Date() } 
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
       sku: 1,
       frequency: 1,
       lastProccessedDate: 1,
    }
}
])
```

First, we transform documents to new form that contains the same fields plus a new temporary field - a "shifted" date that is defined as `lastProccessedDate + frequency (days)` (pay attention that we actually add milliseconds, so there's `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` in the query). Then we select only that documents which `shiftedDate` is less than (or equals) current timestamp (`new Date()` returns current timestamp). Finally, we transform the filtered documents to original form, without the temporary field we used to filter the documents previously.

Perhaps there's a better solution to get documents you want, but this one can resolve your problem too.

Comment: Instead of `$project` you can use `$set`. Then you save all the `xx: 1`